# Docker entry point startup script exec error

Tags: python, bash, docker

I have a docker file that runs:

a simple startup script to create a jinja2 file it is called in the ENTRYPOINT

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./docker-entrypoint.sh"]
CMD ["python test.py", "--config", "config.json"]
```

the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
jinja2 config.json.j2 > config.json
exec "$@"
```

but when I do docker run using this command.

```
docker run test -env tagname="Foo" -env value=300
```

I get:

```
./docker-entrypoint.sh: line 3: exec: -e: invalid option
exec: usage: exec [-cl] [-a name] [command [arguments ...]] [redirection ...]
```

Any ideas what is going on?

Comment: The issue I'm guessing is in your `exec "$@"` line from the stack trace, why does it think `-e`? Also why do you have ` CMD` it should already be handled by `ENTRYPOINT`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The environment variables need to be before your image name.

Everything after it is replacing the CMD. Also, it is `-e` or `--env`, so your dashes were missing to begin with.

You can also just put the python command within the entrypoint file.

Answer (score 0):

Try `docker run -env ... test` instead? My guess is that the trailing `-env` params are passed into the container as parameters for your scripts.

Answer (score 0):

if `-env` is the environment that need pass to the image, you should call :

```
docker run -it -e ENVXX=aa -e ENVYY=bb ImageNameOfTest
```

if `-env` is the param that need pass to your test exe, call :

```
docker run -it ImageNameOfTest test -env xxx -env yyy
```